# Unanswerable "Discussion" Questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed

What are the differences between this question:

[Should there be a regulatory body to regulate the number of developers graduating every year? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114580/should-there-be-a-regulatory-body-to-regulate-the-number-of-developers-graduatin)

And this question:

[What were the reasons why Windows never had a decent shell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114530/what-were-the-reasons-why-windows-never-had-a-decent-shell)

The first was closed by [Mark Trapp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8/mark-trapp) after he commented that Programmers [isn't a discussion board](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). The second has active speculative answers that seem to me to simply be discussions and opinions about the question. Disregarding the quality of the question (the closed one could have been closed simply on that merit) what makes the Shell question worthy of continued discussion?

Comment: [What were the reasons why Windows never had a decent shell?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114530/what-were-the-reasons-why-windows-never-had-a-decent-shell) is now closed.

Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing: community moderation is done by humans and some things slip through the cracks. When that happens, we rely on users like yourself to find the things we missed.

[What were the reasons why Windows never had a decent shell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114530/what-were-the-reasons-why-windows-never-had-a-decent-shell) is just pure speculation like the other question, so it's been closed now too.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I wasn't trying to belabor any point, just seeking (and received) clarification.

Comment: @DaveNay No problem, thanks for pointing it out though. I just reiterated what ChrisF said in his comment to get remove this question from the unanswered list (only happens when a question receives an answer).

Comment: I did try add an answer, but wasn't verbose enough ;)